# WS-Security not working with CXF 3.1 and spring 4

Tags: spring, cxf

I am using the Apache Cxf 3.0.5 with Spring 4.2.5, the web services are secured with WS-Security

Here is the sample header,

test:test
      test

I am using the following interceptor, but unable to get the authentication header information

public class JaxWsAuthenticationInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor {

```
public JaxWsAuthenticationInterceptor() {
    super(Phase.POST_PROTOCOL);
}

public void handleMessage(SoapMessage message) throws Fault {

    List<WSHandlerResult> result = (List<WSHandlerResult>) message.getContextualProperty(WSHandlerConstants.RECV_RESULTS);
    for (WSHandlerResult res : result) {
        for (WSSecurityEngineResult secRes : res.getResults()) {
            Integer action = (Integer) secRes.get(WSSecurityEngineResult.TAG_ACTION);
            if (action != null && (action & WSConstants.UT) > 0) {
                WSUsernameTokenPrincipalImpl principal = (WSUsernameTokenPrincipalImpl) secRes.get(WSSecurityEngineResult.TAG_PRINCIPAL);                    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: How are you configuring CXF on the inbound side? Are you adding the WSS4JInInterceptor or using WS-SecurityPolicy? If so what does the policy look like? In your interceptor, do you see any results at all?

Comment: I am using the spring to configure CXF and using the WS-security policy.My code is working if I used spring 3.2 but same code won't work for spring 4.2

Comment: Here is the sample header 

<soapenv:Header>
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
<wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1">
<wsse:Username>testuser</wsse:Username>
<wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">!amHere</wsse:Password>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>

Comment: I suggest creating a JIRA in CXF + attaching a testcase to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you tell me the jars required for running Apache CXF 3.0 ? I am using the following , 
cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb
cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws
cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs
cxf-rt-transports-http
cxf-rt-ws-security
cxf-rt-management
cxf-tools-common

Comment: I am able to resolve this issue,